# Getting max id by comparing two different database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two same databases on two different servers: one primary and one backup. Users are currently in both servers. We have an OrderId column in tblOrder in both db's as the auto incrementing primary key. Now when I publish the orderid to our amazon server it sometimes shows an error because the orderid on both databases are the same number and a duplicate orderid is not accepted by the system.

I want to get the max orderid from both the server and then give the new orderid to current working database. I will remove the auto incrementing seed from it, so that on insert command I will insert the orderid manually.

Comment: thanks Guys for such a great idea. I will definitely implement it. :-D

Comment: The solution here is to get your production users out of your backup database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solutions:

1. As mentioned already, you can change the increment on each identity field to 2, and have one server with a seed of 1 and the other a seed of 2.
2. Presuming you don't foresee handling more than 1 billion orders on each server, simply set the seed on the second server to 1,000,000,000. No need to change the increment.
3. Use a `uniqueidentifier` (GUID) as your primary key rather than an integer. For SQL Server 2005 and above, you can set a default constraint to NEWSEQUENTIALID() to keep inserts from constantly creating page splits.

Comment: I agree with your opinion but our server daily do a transaction for about 5,000,000 per day. It will work fine. But it is not a permanent solution.  But i will implement the your point 3, it is very usefull indeed. Thanks :-D for sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

In MS-SQL you can  specify a Seed and an Increment for an autonumber field. 
make the Seeds different and set Increment=2

Comment: It may be worth mentioning the difference between the two seeds must be odd :)